Sonar scanner plugin for sbt
I am trying to find a Sonar scanner plugin for SBT which will support the newest versions of SonarQube. But all that I have found is outdated and doesn't work with SonarQube 9+:
sbt-sonar
sonar-scala
Maybe I am searching in a wrong way?

Did you find one?
